# $gte always returns an empty array

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to find rooms that have a capacity greater than or equal to inputted capacity. I'm using the `$gte` operator and it always returns an empty array.

I'm using sequelize and MySQL, and when I try,

```
let allRooms = await Room.findAll({
        where: {
          capacity: 9
        }
      });

I get an array containing the data I'm trying to get.

[ Room {
    dataValues:
     { id: 2,
       name: 'meeting room 1',
       amenities: <Buffer 00 00 00>,
       capacity: 9,
       createdAt: 2019-08-26T18:21:07.000Z,
       updatedAt: 2019-08-26T18:21:07.000Z,
       locationId: 1 }
   }
]
```

but when I try

```
let allRooms = await Room.findAll({
        where: {
          capacity: { $gte: 5 }
        }
      });

it returns  // []
```

and in my terminal, I get this

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `amenities`, `capacity`, 
`createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `locationId` FROM `Rooms` AS `Room`
 WHERE `Room`.`capacity` = '[object Object]';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```js
const Op = Sequelize.Op

let allRooms = await Room.findAll({
        where: {
          capacity: { [Op.gte]: 5 }
        }
      });
```

**EDIT:**

Alias needs to be declared before use

```js
const Op = Sequelize.Op
const operatorsAliases = {
  $gte: Op.gte
}

let allRooms = await Room.findAll({
        where: {
          capacity: { $gte: 5 }
        }
      });
```

Comment: @neydoo I have updated the answer if you want to use $gte